# 7zip extract *.zip in subfolder

Tags: batch-file, 7zip, subdirectory

I have many *.zip files in many subfolders. I tried to extract all of them by batch file with this command but it does not work. How can I fix it?

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.zip') do (7z.exe l -r "%%A" >> listing.txt)
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/9356/7-zip-how-to-list-contents-of-a-folder-and-subfolder-of-zip-files-without-extracting-win-xpvista7-and-command-line/).

Comment: I guess the `>>` redirector should be escaped as follows `^>^>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command, it should do what it sounds like you are looking for:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`dir /b /s *.zip`) DO (
    REM Extract each zip file to a folder with same name as the file.
    7z x "%%A" -o"%%~dpA"
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly
My folder tree:
--parent
  |
  ----folder1
  |    |
  |    file1.zip 
  |         |
  |         file1.doc
  ----folder2
       |
       file2.zip 
            |
            file2.doc

I need "file1.doc" in "folder1" and "file2.doc" in "folder2" after extract, but your batch file extract them into "parent" folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`dir /b *.zip`) DO (
    REM Extract each zip file to a folder with same name as the file.
    7z e "%%A" -o"%%~dnA"
)
```

this works for me